# Mocking JobExplorer using @MockBean throwing an Exception: InstanceAlreadyException

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-batch-tasklet

**"How can i mock JobExecution while testing a Single step using 
  JobLauncherTestUtils?"**

"i`ve tried with

```
@MockBean JobExplorer jobExplorer
```

but it is throwing an Exception:

```
Failed to load applicationContext,Caused by InstanceAlreadyExistsException
```

but it works fine when i am running it individually.So i tried to use

```
@Mock JobExplorer jobExplorer;
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
}
```

but This one not even working :( Then i added

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
@Configuartion(...)
class MockTest{
@Mock JobExplorer jobExplorer
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
}
```

}

Main Code:

---

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Configuration(classes=TestConfig.class)
Class MockTest{
   private static final String jobName ="job";
   @Autowired JobLauncherTestUtils;
   @Autowired JobRegistry jobRegistry;
   @MockBean JobExplorer jobExplorer;
@Before
public void setUp(){
   Job job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobName);
   JobInstance jobInstance = new JobInstance(0L,job.getName());
   JobExecution jobExecution = new JobExecution(0L);
   jobExecution.setJobInstance(jobInstance);
}
@Test
public testMock(){
   //jobParams
   Data data = new Data();
   ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
   context.put("data",Data);
   jobExecution.setExecutionContext(context);
   when(jobExplorer.getJobExecution(any()).thenReturn(jobExecution);
   JobExecution jobExecution = testUtils.launchStep("stepname",context);
}
@After
public void tearDown(){
//statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have keep in mind that simply using:

```
@Mock JobExecution jobExecution
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
}
```

does not cause an injection of that mocked instance to where you expect it, or where it is declared as an instance variable.

This code is fine and you do not need to use `@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)` on top of it.

What you need to do is to inject / set `jobExecution` instance manually in your `@Test` or `@Before` method.